# How to create a custom filter template in the Django admin interface?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My goal is to put a custom input field in the filter list box on my Django interface. I found no way of doing this with standard tools so I want to create a new template for the filter box.

In the official [Django doc on the admin interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options), there's this:

> It is possible to specify a custom template for rendering a list filter:

```
class FilterWithCustomTemplate(admin.SimpleListFilter):
        template = "custom_template.html"
```

> See the default template provided by Django (admin/filter.html) for a concrete example.

But no more details are given. How am I supposed to implement this? `filter.html` does not extend `change_list.html` and I don't know where I am supposed to put my new custom filter template (I tried in `templates/admin/my_app_name` with the rest of my other overriding templates but it doesn't work)

How can I create a new template for my admin filter box ?

Comment: Try including the path to the template: `template = "admin/my_app_name/custom_template.html"`

Comment: @evergreen It doesn't work

Comment: In my projects I have the template inside the templates folder in the app where the custom filter is defined, Mine is at `templates/app_name/admin/custom_template.html` and it works okay.

Comment: In my case the admin and app_name and folders are reverse so I have `templates/admin/app_name/custom_template.html`. I tried your solution (with and without including the path in the class) and it didn't work, but with your solution the rest of my custom admin templates is also ignored. I think I will try to do this "manually" by overriding the filter bloc in `change_list.html`